# What folders do I need to backup to be able to downgrade from Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, backup, windows-10

I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 2 weeks ago which was not as smooth as I expected but everything seems to work. (Except Cortana, but I'm never going to use that anyway).

I understand that Microsoft gives users a 30 day window from the day they upgraded to Windows 10, in which to downgrade back to the version of Windows they had before. However I read somewhere that there are certain folders or files that if you back up, you will be able to keep the availability to downgrade beyond the 30 day limit. If this is true, what are the folders or files I need to backup? and assuming I have all of the necessary data to downgrade, how would I?

Comment: The folder that cannot be deleted is Windows.old but more importantly you cannot run the Clean utility and then select the option that wipes your previous installation

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer?

Comment: There really isn't anything to expand on.  If you don't run the utility and don't remove the Windows.old your ability to revert back to the previous installation of Windows will remain possible for 30 days.